# How to translate these pseudo unicode data declaration code into MASM style code?

Tags: winapi, unicode, masm, masm32

I have some pseudo asm code generated from IDA Pro like this:

```
aR6033AttemptTo:
unicode 0, <R6033>
dw 0Dh, 0Ah
unicode 0, <- Attempt to use MSIL code >
unicode 0, <from this assembly during n>
unicode 0, <ative code initialization>
```

and this variable is used in this way:

```
dd offset aR6033AttemptTo
```

I know if there is an one line unicode declaration, I can use this :

```
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
....
WSTR aNull_0, "this is a unicode string"
```

But how can I deal with multilines declaration? Especially there are **dw 0Dh, 0Ah**, could anyone give me some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the UNICODE string yourself?!?!

A normal string is ASCII - 1 byte per character (declared as BYTE), a UNICODE string is 2 bytes per character (declared as WORD)

```
UniString       word    'I', 13, 10, \
                        'a','m', 13, 10, \
                        'a', 13, 10, \
                        'M','u','l','t','i', ' ', 'l','i','n','e', 13, 10, \
                        'U','N','I','C','O','D','E', ' ', 's','t','r','i', 'n', 'g','!',0, 0
```

Let's test it with a Unicode `MessageBox`

```
Invoke MessageBoxW, 0, offset UniString, NULL, MB_ICONINFORMATION
```

[image]

Now, all that typing can be tedious, I sure didn't type all that out.  I have a program with source, that when you input a variable name, some ASCII text, and it will output your string as a UNICODE defined string. [Unicode String Variable Creator](http://www.gunnerinc.com/usvc.htm)  The one at the link, will only do single line strings.  You can modify it to create multi line strings as I did.  Change the bottom 2 edit controls to richtext controls modify the conversion loop to add the 13 an 10 for Carriage Return and Line Feeds.